# AdminJS how to make field mandatory

Tags: adminjs

I have been looking for a long time and I have no idea how to do it, do you have a simple solution to make a field mandatory in the action/new or edit pages ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `isRequired:true` to the field. See the document [here](https://docs.adminjs.co/PropertyOptions.html#isRequired)

```
 ....
 resource: YourResource,
 options: {
   properties: {
      YourField : {isRequired: true}
   }
 }
 ....
```